# Passing multiple arguments from a macro to a lua function

Tags: tikz-pgf, lua

The problem is to obtain the barycenter of any number of points. If `lua` is not used then `TikZ` is used otherwise `lua`. (Sorry the question is long)

With only `TikZ' the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\barycenter(#1)#2{%
\path[coordinate]  (barycentric cs:#1) coordinate (#2);}
\begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (2,5);
\barycenter(A=1,B=1,C=1){G} % #1 the list A=1,B=1,C=1 #2 G barycenter
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\node[circle, inner sep = 0pt,fill=lightgray,
  draw=black,minimum size =4pt] at (G) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> For the coordinate system barycentric, the ⟨coordinate specification⟩
> should be a comma-separated list of expressions of the form ⟨node
> name⟩=⟨number⟩. Note that (currently) the list should not contain any
> spaces before or after the ⟨node name⟩ (unlike normal key–value
> pairs).

Without transfer to lua, the code is as follows: (some explanations are necessary and they follow the code)

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,luacode}
\directlua{bary = require("bary")}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\luadirect{
require "complex"
z = {}
z.A = complex.new (1,0)
z.B = complex.new (5,-1)
z.C = complex.new (2,5)
z.G = barycenter ({z.A,1},{z.B,1},{z.C,1})
for K,V in pairs(z) do
    tex.print("\\coordinate ("..K..") at ("..V.re..","..V.im..") ;")
end
}
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\node[circle, inner sep = 0pt,fill=lightgray,
  draw=black,minimum size =4pt] at (G) {};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

The barycenter function is in the file `bary.lua` that here is

```
function barycenter (...)
    local cp = table.pack(...)
    local i
    local sum = 0
    local weight=0
    for i=1,cp.n do
        sum = sum + cp[i][1]*cp[i][2]
        weight = weight + cp[i][2]
    end
  return sum/weight
end
```

The function is based on the calculation with complex numbers, also you have to download the library `complex.lua` here https://gist.github.com/MihailJP/3500284

`z ={}`creates the table, the keys are the names of the points which will be future "nodes" and the values are obviously the coordinates
of the points.

`z.C = complex.new (2,5)` associates the point `C` with its affix
`z.C = 2+5i`.

The barycenter is obtained with  `z.G = barycenter ({z.A,1},{z.B,1},{z.C,1})`

The question: how to modify the next macro to call the barycenter function.

```
\def\barycenter(#1)#2{%
\path[coordinate]  (barycentric cs:#1) coordinate (#2);
% How to replace the previous line to call the barycenter function of lua ?
}
```

The problem is how to go from `A=1,B=1,C=1` to `{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}` knowing that it can be for two, three or even four points! I don't know if it is better to work on arguments in `TeX` or in `lua`.

Update of the question: Unfortunately I made a mistake because to work with affixes you have to go from `A=1,B=1,C=1` to
`{z.A,1},{z.B,1},{z.C,1}` and not to `{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is how to go from `A=1,B=1,C=1` to `{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}` knowing that it can be for two, three or even four points! I don't know if it is better to work on arguments in `TeX` or in `lua`.

It is very easy to do with TeX.
Here's a user-level solution with just what TikZ provides already.

PGFKeys and PGFFor provides the `.list` handler which loops over a list (via `\foreach`) without its body being grouped.

For each element in your list `<node>=<weight>` the element `{<x>,<y>,<weight>}` will be added to a list which is just a value-key (here `/utils/tempa`) which later can be fully expanded.

The first element will be handled differently because we don't want a `,` at the start.

Unfortunately, PGFKeys loses some braces on the way which makes it necessary to use four pairs when initializing the value. Though, we can fallback to the `\pgfkeyssetvalue` macro (which is just a fancy `\def`).

---

Using PGFkeys (mostly `\pgfkeysaddvalue`) avoids
higher level packages like `etoolbox` (`\appto`) or `l3clist` (`\clist_put_right:Nn`) and using PGFFor (via `.list`) avoids lower level loops (like `\pgfutil@for` or LaTeX's `\@for`) which are faster, most likely.

---

I'll provide a different `barycenter` Lua function that doesn't use any complex numbers but just returns two values which will be forwarded to PGF directly.

The usage of `\tikz@parse@node` makes sure that `name prefix` and `name suffix` gets used if necessary when accessing the coordinates (could be nodes even).
The same is true for `\tikz@pp@name` when defining the new coordinate.

In the code below I've define both `#2'` via the `barycentric cs` (red cross) and just `#2` via Lua (circle).

---

For the Lua solution via `.list`, spaces before the `,` are allowed, however spaces before the `=` will still raise an error – just as they do for TikZ' own `barycentric cs`.

---

With the same definition of `\tikz@baryget` as in the main code and with these two additions:

```
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary}{
  .unknown/.code=%
    \let\tikz@key\pgfkeyscurrentname
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary/@@add/.expanded={\tikz@key}{#1}},
  @@initial/.style={
    @@add/.code 2 args=%
      \tikz@parse@node\tikz@baryget(##1)%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary/@@temp}{{\tikz@temp,##2}}%
      \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary/@@add/.code 2 args=%
        \tikz@parse@node\tikz@baryget(####1)%
        \edef\tikz@temp{\noexpand\pgfkeysaddvalue
          {/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary/@@temp}{,{\tikz@temp,####2}}}%
        \tikz@temp},
  }
}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{Lua barycentric}{%
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/cs/@Lua@bary/.cd,@@initial,#1}%
  \directlua{
    sumx, sumy = barycenter(\pgfkeysvalueof{/utils/bary from lua/to lua})
    tex.print("\\pgfqpoint{"..sumx.."pt}{"..sumy.."pt}")
  }%
}
```

a coordinate specification like

```
\draw[green] (Lua barycentric cs: A = 1, B = 1, C = 1) circle[radius=4pt];
```

is possible without having to deal with any spaces (since PGFKeys parses the list) and it allows to specify the coordinate on-the-fly without an extra macro.

It also doesn't use PGFFor anymore. (A combination of both is possible.)

### Code

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\directlua{
function barycenter (...)
  local cp = table.pack(...)
  local i
  local sumx = 0
  local sumy = 0
  local weight = 0
  for i=1,cp.n do
      sumx = sumx + cp[i][1]*cp[i][3]
      sumy = sumy + cp[i][2]*cp[i][3]
      weight = weight + cp[i][3]
  end
  return sumx/weight, sumy/weight
end
}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@baryget#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \edef\tikz@temp{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x,\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}}%
\pgfkeys{
  /utils/bary from lua/.style args={#1,#2}{
    /utils/temp/.code args={##1=##2}{%
      \tikz@parse@node\tikz@baryget(##1)%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/utils/bary from lua/to lua}{{\tikz@temp,##2}}},
    /utils/temp={#1},
    /utils/temp/.code args={##1=##2}{%
      \tikz@parse@node\tikz@baryget(##1)%
      \edef\tikz@temp{\noexpand\pgfkeysaddvalue
        {/utils/bary from lua/to lua}{}{,{\tikz@temp,##2}}}%
      \tikz@temp},
    /utils/temp/.list={#2}}}
\def\barycenter(#1)#2{%
  \coordinate (#2') at (barycentric cs:#1);
  \pgfutil@in@{,}{#1}% just in case
  \ifpgfutil@in@
    \pgfkeys{/utils/bary from lua={#1}}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{/utils/bary from lua={#1,}}% \foreach ignores empty
  \fi
  \directlua{
    sumx, sumy = barycenter(\pgfkeysvalueof{/utils/bary from lua/to lua})
    tex.print("\\pgfcoordinate{\\csname tikz@pp@name\\endcsname{#2}}
                              {\\pgfqpoint{"..sumx.."pt}{"..sumy.."pt}}")
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (2,5);
\barycenter(A=1,B=1,C=1){G}
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\node[circle, inner sep = 0pt, fill=lightgray,
  draw=black, minimum size =4pt] at (G) {};
\draw[red] (G') +(north west:2pt) -- +(south east:2pt)
                +(north east:2pt) -- +(south west:2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It seems that getting `{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}` is not my only problem. I admit I don't know how to get this into `Lua`. In addition to the difficulties of `TeX`, there is also the difficulties of `Lua`.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I'm not proficient in Lua(TeX) but I'll updated my answer with two changes: 1. the *x* and *y* values get converted by TeX to float numbers for Lua and 2. Lua calculates the new coordinate without any complex numbers.

Comment: @AlainMatthes You might need to evaluate the weight before giving it to Lua since it could include PGFMath function that won't be understood by Lua.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first solution was fine ! I made a mistake because to use the complexes the arguments for lua are `{z.A,1},{z.B,1},{z.C,1}`. Your first code works fine with `\barycenter(z.A=1,z.B=1,z.C=1){G}` but in this case there is a problem without lua. I can also use a little trick and before determining the barycenter do `A=z.A B=z.B et C=z.C`. The best is that I try to modify the code of PGFKeys.

Comment: The second code is good too and I could reintroduce the complexes before the création of "coordinate". However, I prefer to stay with complex because I want to allow users to be able to create all the necessary points while staying in lua. It's simpler and more efficient, then to create the nodes at the end and switch to TikZ.

Comment: I could not modify the barycenter function with lua because a large part of all my functions use complex numbers, barycentric coordinates and the barycenter function.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Shouldn't it be just as easy as inserting `z.` here `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/utils/tempa}{{z.##1,##2}}` and the same for the others? Unless it's not always `z.`? It seems I didn't really answered your question with the current state of my answer. Should I update it?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Aren't you using Complex numbers in the place of two-dimensional variables? Seems like a misuse of Complex numbers but maybe it's a good approach given limitations by Lua?

Comment: Yes it was easy to insert z. here \pgfkeyssetvalue{/utils/tempa}{{z.##1,##2}}. No problem. I discovered `.list` et I didn't find much in the documentation. I didn't even find `pgfkeysaddvalue`.

Comment: About complex numbers: Yes I use them in the place of two-dimensional variables. But this has several advantages. The functions are easier to write. For example for rotations, working with polar forms. I was able to create mathematical tools like the calculation of determinants (Cramer) . Intersections of objects are easier. I can introduce some object programming. For the moment by replacing fp and xfpd in `tkz-euclide` by lua, I have already gained in precision and about 30% of compilation time. barycenter and complex are very useful

Comment: If I use only lua for the calculations, it is easy, precise and fast to obtain everything that tkz-euclide does. We finish with TikZ for plots and labels. The disadvantage is that you have to master lua so I decided to rewrite my macros this time only with lua. I admit that this time I don't know what the gain will be but it's interesting. For the user it will be transparent. The example with the barycenter is typical. The syntax remains the same for the user.